# Blood Group in Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I would like to integrate an application on a website with which potential donors can find out which blood groups are compatible with their own blood group. I have used the below code using JS but apparently I made mistake somewhere!. I am just a beginner  I would appreciate it to guide me to learn and also fix the code in JavaScript.

```
var FirstName = prompt("Enter your name: ", "green");
        var age = parseInt(prompt("Enter your age: ", "18"));
        var bloodType = prompt("Enter your blood type: ");
        bloodType = bloodType.toLowerCase();
        var res;

      if (age >= 18 || age <= 66) {
                    switch (true) {
                          case 'o-';
                    alert("Hello" FirstName ". Since you have blood type"
                        bloodType "yourself,can donate blood to people with the blood group  O-, O +, A-, A +, B-, B +, AB-, AB +.");
                    break;


                    case 'o+';
                    alert("Hello"
                        FirstName ". Since you have blood type"
                        bloodType "yourself ,can donate blood to people with the blood group O +, A +, B +, AB +.");
                    break;

                    default:
                        alert('Default case');
                        break;
                          .
                          .
                          .
                          .
                          .

    }else {
                    alert ('Your age does not meet the requirements for giving blood.');
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take `bloodType` as switch value and compare it with the various types, as required for the [`switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

```js
var firstName = prompt("Enter your name: ", "green"),
    age = parseInt(prompt("Enter your age: ", "18"), 10),
    bloodType = prompt("Enter your blood type: ").toLowerCase(),
    res;

if (age >= 18 || age <= 66) {
    switch (bloodType) {
        case 'o-':
            alert("Hello " + firstName + ". Since you have blood type " + bloodType + " your can donate blood to people with the blood group  O-, O+, A-, A+, B-, B+, AB-, AB+.");
            break;
        case 'o+':
            alert("Hello " + firstName + ". Since you have blood type " + bloodType + " you can donate blood to people with the blood group O+, A+, B+, AB+.");
            break;
        default:
            alert('Default case');
    }
} else {
    alert('Your age does not meet the requirements for giving blood.');
}
```

Comment: I did whatever you said but still without a result.